# How to download the manufacturing ontology for integrating with my digital twins models from GitHub?

Tags: github, ontology, azure-digital-twins

I am working on my digital twins models for a simulated manufacturing environment. I've found a manufacturing ontology on GitHub, but I don't know how to download and import it into my project.

The GitHub repository is https://github.com/digitaltwinconsortium/ManufacturingOntologies, and it appears to contain the ontology I need. However, I'm relatively new to using GitHub and would appreciate some guidance on the following:

What is the recommended method for downloading this manufacturing ontology from the GitHub repository?

Are there any specific branches or releases I should be aware of, or is the master branch typically the one to use?

Once I've downloaded the ontology, what steps should I follow to integrate it into my digital twins models?

Are there any best practices or considerations I should keep in mind when working with external ontologies in the context of digital twins?

Any advice, step-by-step instructions, or recommended tools and libraries for handling this process would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

What I tried:
I visited the GitHub repository mentioned in the question and could not find the manufacturing ontology file to download the ontology.

What I expected to happen:
I expected to find a folder with the applicable files. I would be able to extract the ontology files from it and then import them into my digital twins models.

What actually resulted:
I found that it contained the entire repository, including source code, documentation, and various other files. I was unsure if I had found the right URL.

I'm seeking guidance on the recommended method for downloading the manufacturing ontology (if available in the mentioned URL), ensuring I have the correct files, and effectively importing them into my digital twins models.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the community! The GitHub resource you have provided is meant to act as a guide for building a solution on manufacturing ontology using OPC UA Cloud publisher among various other sources as data source. The repository offers guidance on a complex architecture which might be involved in manufacturing scenarios. You certainly do not have to follow the same architecture provided in the repository.

According to the documentation [What is an ontology?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/concepts-ontologies), "*An ontology is a set of models that comprehensively describe a given domain, like manufacturing, building structures, IoT systems, smart cities, energy grids, web content, and more.*" Assuming you are looking for model definitions to import into your Digital Twin instance, you can find them under the [Ontologies](https://github.com/digitaltwinconsortium/ManufacturingOntologies/tree/main/Ontologies) directory. There are no specific branches you would need to download. The easiest way to obtain this is by Choosing the `Download zip` option by clicking on code on the [repository page](https://github.com/digitaltwinconsortium/ManufacturingOntologies). This will get you a local copy of the repository contents. Alternatively, you can use the GitHub command `git clone https://github.com/digitaltwinconsortium/ManufacturingOntologies` from command prompt/bash to clone the repository to your local directory. You can keep a copy of Ontologies directory and delete the rest.

Now that you have the models downloaded, you may inspect and import all models or just a few of them based on your use case. You can use an [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-manage-model#upload-small-model-sets) or [Jobs API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-manage-model#upload-large-model-sets-with-the-jobs-api) to import the models. Once the models are imported, you can create Digital twins of these models. Please refer the resource [Ingest IoT Hub telemetry into Azure Digital Twins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-ingest-iot-hub-data) to get more details on how to ingest telemetry data from IoT Hub to a digital twin. You can use this approach to simulate data instead of using the architecture provided in the GitHub repository.

Hope this helps. Cheers!